# Magento2: How to add simple product in configurable product dropdown

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

How to add the simple product in a configurable product? And How to redirect parent product in a Configurable product.

Magento 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I have created a module for Configurable. You need to follow the below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create file **module.xml** under:

> /app/code/STech/Configurable/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Configurable" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
</config>
```

**Step 2:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> /app/code/STech/Configurable/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Configurable',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 3:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> /app/code/STech/Configurable/etc/di.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
        <plugin name="stech_configurable_product_controller_view" type="STech\Configurable\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> /app/code/STech/Configurable/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Product/View.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Configurable\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product;

class View
{
    protected $http;

    protected $productHelper;

    protected $configurable;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $http,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable
    ) {
        $this->http = $http;
        $this->productHelper =$productHelper;
        $this->configurable = $configurable;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $productId = (int) $subject->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $parentIds = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
        $parentId = array_shift($parentIds);

        if($parentId) {
            $categoryId = (int)$subject->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
            $productId = (int)$parentId;

            $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);

            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $product */
            $product = $this->productHelper->initProduct($productId, $subject, $params);;
            $this->http->setRedirect($product->getProductUrl(), 301);
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Thats its. Flush the cache. Run setup upgrade and other required commands and check.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you tell me where add above files?

Comment: Do you how to create module?

Comment: Can you check my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, I will update and let you know.

Comment: Why? I have already asked clearly that you need to create module. I have write down all the steps where to create the files and what will be the content of the files.

Comment: Ok, I am creating the new module.

Comment: I have created new module. Please tell me next step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82421/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-masud-shaikh).